# Windows Phone 8. C#. Lockscreen background from isolated storage. Exception

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, lockscreen, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to implement a lockscreen background application on Windows Phone 8 using C#. The idea is that when a user clicks a button, PhotoChooserTask is initiated. When he picks a photo from his media library, it's copied to isolated storage and then set as a lockscreen background.

The problem is that Windows Phone requires a unique name for each new lockscreen picture, so the solution has to be the following:

1. The user selects a photo from the library
   2.1 If the current lockscreen picture **EndsWith("_A.jpg")** the chosen photo is copied to the isolated storage as **photobackground_B.jpg** and is set as lockscreen background
   2.2. Otherwise, if the current lockscreen picture doesn't meet the **EndsWith("_A.jpg")** condition, then the chosen photo is copied to the isolated storage as **photobackground_A.jpg** and is set as lockscreen background.

Thus, the A/B switching logic is implemented so that each new lockscreen background has a unique name.

However, my code does not work.In particular the following line throws an exception:

```
Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(new Uri("ms-appdata:///Local/photobackground_A.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```

What seems to be the problem?

P.S. I'm completely new to programming, so I would also greately appreciate an explanation and a proper code sample. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using Day2Demo.Resources;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;


namespace Day2Demo
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask;
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }





        private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            //check if current app provided the lock screen image
            if (!Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication)
            {
                //current image not set by current app ask permission
                var permission = await Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync();

                if (permission == Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreenRequestResult.Denied)
                {
                    //no permission granted so return without setting the lock screen image
                    return;
                }

            }
            photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
            photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
            photoChooserTask.Show();
        }

        void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                var currentImage = Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.GetImageUri();
                if (currentImage.ToString().EndsWith("_A.jpg"))
                {

                    var contents = new byte[1024];
                    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        using (var local = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("photobackground_B.jpg", FileMode.Create, store))
                        {
                            int bytes;
                            while ((bytes = e.ChosenPhoto.Read(contents, 0, contents.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                local.Write(contents, 0, bytes);
                            }

                        }
                        Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(new Uri("ms-appdata:///Local/photobackground_B.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    var contents = new byte[1024];
                    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        using (var local = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("photobackground_A.jpg", FileMode.Create, store))
                        {
                            int bytes;
                            while ((bytes = e.ChosenPhoto.Read(contents, 0, contents.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                local.Write(contents, 0, bytes);
                            }

                        }
                        Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(new Uri("ms-appdata:///Local/photobackground_A.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions for you:

1. You may be overcomplicating the matter of naming the file. First, I'd say if the app is the current lock screen manager, delete the existing lock screen image, then create a new image name using [Guid.NewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Guids are guaranteed to be unique upon generation so you'll never run into a naming collision here.
2. You're using antiquated storage APIs that may lock your UI and cause it to become non-responsive. There are new async file storage APIs provided in Windows Phone 8 and it might help to familiarize yourself with them in the future. The code sample provided will give you a start.
3. The URI you're ultimately going to provide is likely most easily generated by giving the OS a system-relative file path (i.e. C:\) and that's easily accessible from the [StorageFile.Path Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.path.aspx).

Modify your event handler to something along the lines of the following code and see how you fare. **You will need to add a using directive to import the System.IO namespace to use the [OpenStreamForWriteAsync Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582147.aspx)**:

```
private async void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        // Load the image source into a writeable bitmap
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bi);

        // Buffer the photo content in memory (90% quality; adjust parameter as needed)
        byte[] buffer = null;

        using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            int quality = 90;
            e.ChosenPhoto.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // TODO: Crop or rotate here if needed
            // Resize the photo by changing parameters to SaveJpeg() below if desired

            wb.SaveJpeg(ms, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, quality);
            buffer = ms.ToArray();
        }

        // Save the image to isolated storage with new Win 8 APIs
        var isoFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var nextImageName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg";
        var newImageFile = await isoFolder.CreateFileAsync(nextImageName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
        using (var wfs = await newImageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            wfs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        // Use the path property of the StorageFile to set the lock screen URI
        Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(new Uri(newImageFile.Path, UriKind.Absolute));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The new API seems to work perfectly in terms of saving the image to isolated storage. However, the ' Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(new Uri(newImageFile.Path, UriKind.Absolute));' throws an exception(

Answer (score 1):

Thanks lthibodeaux for the awesome idea) Everything worked except for the SetImageUri line.

This one seems to do the business: Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(new Uri("ms-appdata:///Local/" + nextImageName, UriKind.Absolute))

Thanks again!